# Parsing a string to an array output from command line

Tags: php, regex, bash, symfony, docker

I'm working on a new Symfony 2 project which will be a panel management for Docker containers.

In this project, I'm executing some commands with the `exec()` PHP function.

I'm trying to parse the output of the following command :

```
docker create tutum/lamp:latest --name test 2>&1
```

When the command is a success I'm getting the container ID in a string which is good and easy to use but when a problem occured it's not the same. The result is a string with a var="data" syntax which I want to parse in order to get an array.

The command output :

```
time="2015-06-21T11:33:26+02:00" level="fatal" msg="Error response from daemon: Conflict. The name \"test\" is already in use by container XXXXXXXX. You have to delete (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name."
```

I wish to have something like that :

```
Array( time => "2015-06-21T11:33:26+02:00", level => "fatal" ...);
```

I know that I have to do a regex parsing. After a while (regex and me are not realy best friends) I get this regex (tested on https://regex101.com/) :

```
/([a-zA-Z]+)="((.*)*)"/
```

I used preg_split function i'm not sure that it's the good one.

```
preg_split('/([a-zA-Z]+)="((.*)*)"/', $output)
```

Result is :

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" }
```

Have you any suggestions to help me ?
Many thanks for your help.

Comment: what happens if you just var_dump($output)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR:** This should work:

```
preg_match_all(',([a-z]+)="((?:[^"]|\\\\")*[^\\\\])",', $a, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
var_dump($matches);
```

The last `var_dump` prints the following data structure, which should be easy to process:

```
array(3) {
  [0] => array(3) {
    [0] => string(32) "time="2015-06-21T11:33:26+02:00""
    [1] => string(4) "time"
    [2] => string(25) "2015-06-21T11:33:26+02:00"
  }
  [1] => array(3) {
    [0] => string(13) "level="fatal""
    [1] => string(5) "level"
    [2] => string(5) "fatal"
  }
  [2] => array(3) {
    [0] => string(179) "msg="Error response from daemon: Conflict. The name \\"test\\" is already in use by container XXXXXXXX. You have to delete (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.""
    [1] => string(3) "msg"
    [2] => string(173) "Error response from daemon: Conflict. The name \\"test\\" is already in use by container XXXXXXXX. You have to delete (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name."
  }
}
```

#### Why this works

The regular expression explained:

```
([a-z]+)                    # Match the label ("time", "level" or "msg")
=                           # Self-explanatory
"((?:[^"]|\\\\")*[^\\\\])"  # This is the tricky part:
                            # Match the quoted string; this is a sequence
                            # of (a) non-quote characters ([^"]) or
                            # (b) escaped quote characters (\\\\").
```

Some other notes:

1. `preg_split` uses the regular expression to match token at which the string should be split. That's not what you want in this case; you want to return the parts of the string that was *matched* by the regular expression. For this, you should use `preg_match` (or if, like here, you want a pattern to match multiple times), `preg_match_all`.
2. Also consider the `PREG_SET_ORDER` flag for `preg_match_all`. This flag causes the `$matches` result to contain one row for each label from output message, which makes the data structure easy to process. Try and see what happens if you leave it out.

Comment: You're awesome thanks for your help. 

If I understand it good :
 \\\\" is only for parsing \" right ? So, for example, if I want to escape \n I have to put \\\\n ?

Comment: Happy to help; yes, otherwise the pattern would stop matching at the first quotation mark (escaped or not).

Answer (score 2):

It's because of the [greedy dot](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#greedytrap) that eats up your string to the last `"`. Make it lazy, would do like that:

```
if(preg_match_all('/(\w+)="(.*?)(?<!\\\)"/s', $str, $out))
  print_r(array_combine($out[1], $out[2]));
```

`\w` is a [short](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) for `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. The lookbehind `(?<!\\\)` to eat up escaped quotes ([see regex101](https://regex101.com/r/pH9bC5/2)).

Used `s` flag for making the dot match newline. [Test at eval.in](https://eval.in/384944), *outputs to:*

> Array
>   (
>       [time] => 2015-06-21T11:33:26+02:00
>       [level] => fatal
>       [msg] => Error response from daemon: Conflict. The name \"test\" is already in use by container XXXXXXXX. You have to delete (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.
>   )